# Метод не работает для устройств на Android 7.0, в чём разница?

Tags: android

На устройствах Android 5.0 и 6.0 всё хорошо работает, но на 7.0 уже при работе метода выходит ошибка:

> Cannot run program "arescam": error=13, Permission denied.

Сам метод:

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public void execCmd(String cmd) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            Log.e("mylog", "Execute: " + cmd);
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("mylog", "Can't execute: " + cmd + " " + e);
        }
    }
```

На вход методу подается `cmd = "arescam -a https://blabla.ru/ca/ -k -d"`.
Подскажите в чём может быть проблема? Может быть для Android 7.0 и выше нужно добавить какое-то дополнительное разрешение?

Comment: попробуйте добавить разрешение: `chmod u+x arescam -a https://blabla.ru/ca/ -k -d`

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!

Comment: а зачем нужны такие команды? Просто я никогда не сталкивался, мне интересно

Comment: Рад помочь) Тогда добавлю как ответ

Comment: Про chmod можно почитать на wiki) 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте разрешение: `chmod u+x arescam -a https://blabla.ru/ca/ -k -d`